# Wordpress custom GutenBerg block not showing in inserter dialog

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

So, I am working on a plugin for woo-commerce in WordPress, and now am trying to build a widget.
I have successfully build a custom widget which can be shown across the store (under appearance > widgets).
Now I would like to build a custom Gutenberg Block for use in the page-editor.
The problem right now is that even a simple sample doesn't seem to load, but there is also not even 1 error message anywhere, so I am kinda clueless about how to continue.

I used the sample from WordPress docs itself, and as they state, with this simple example the block should be initialized in the **' inserter dialog'**.

Code I have is >

block.jsx (file used is compiled by webpack, loaded and console log shows up):

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

const blockStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#900',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: '20px',
};
 console.log("test1");
registerBlockType('gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Example: Basic (esnext)',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'design',
    example: {},
    edit() {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps( { style: blockStyle } );
        return <div {...blockProps}>Hello World, step 1 (from the editor).</div>;
    },
    save() {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( { style: blockStyle } );
        return <div {...blockProps}>Hello World, step 1 (from the front-end).</div>;
    },
} );
```

blockload.php (tested the add action("init") but doesn't seem to do much either:

```
<?php
// if (! defined( "ABSPATH")){
//     exit;
// };

function gutenberg_examples_01_register_block() {
 
 // automatically load dependencies and version
//  $asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php');
$asset_file = array('dependencies' => array('wp-element', 'wp-polyfill'), 'version' => 'fc93c4a9675c108725227db345898bcc');

 wp_register_script(
     'gutenberg-examples-01-esnext',
     plugins_url('wocom_bl/resources/Scripts/bundles/editpage/editpage.bundle.js'),
    //  plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
     $asset_file['dependencies'],
     $asset_file['version']
 );

 register_block_type( 'gutenberg-examples/example-01-basic-esnext', array(
     'editor_script' => 'gutenberg-examples-01-esnext',
 ) );

}
// add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_examples_01_register_block' );
add_action('enqueue_block_assets', 'gutenberg_examples_01_register_block');
```

and the main plugin file call which starts everything:

```
if ( wcmbl_isWooCommerceActivated() ) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/settings.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/products/producttab.php';
    // require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/page/register_widgets.php';
     require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/page/blocks/blockload.php';
}
```

So any syntax error inside the blockload.php will throw an error.
as I have posted it now, everything loads fine, no error anywhere (wp_bugging, true)
BUT there is also not a extra block under the design category in the inserter dialog?

So where would I start to find the culprit now?

EDIT **

So, basically I have no idea what was wrong with the initial js, as it was from the sample on dev.wordpress.

I went with a slightly alternative approach how js returns the content, but it works.
Followed this example (edit2 >> tho this uses a deprecated function I see now, so shouldn't be used, but got something working so the rest is out of the scope of this question):
https://themes.artbees.net/blog/create-a-custom-block-for-wordpress-gutenberg/

So question closed!

Comment: I just checked how my normal setup is and I furthermore have `wp-blocks` and `wp-block-editor` in my dependencies array (PHP) and I am using the `init` hook for registering the block instead of `enqueue_block_assets`. And maybe...did you reactivate the plugin after making changes?

Comment: Tried what u suggested but still not any response from front-end..
Also, is that a something I should need to do?
I have already built stuff for woocommerce settings, edit-product settings, plugin tab etc, not once I needed to reactivate my plugin?

Answer (score -1):

Please use `create-guten-block` dev-toolkit for gutenberg blocks development.

I hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: That seems to generate an entire new plugin? I would rather have a solution where the blocks I created are part of the plugin I am currently working on

Comment: Adding Multiple Blocks to a WordPress Plugin in a few steps by Aurooba Makes
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_4loYiEcbg or Creating a plugin with @wordpress/create-blocks that has multiple blocks  - Ryan Welcher Codes  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwXXckW3dT0